# How to recover Hyper-V Guest Domain Controller from Stop Error 0xc00002e2

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, bsod, stoperror

Host is Server 2012 with single Hyper-V guest which is a Domain Controller. When booting the DC it gives a Blue Stop Error: 0xc00002e2 and then reboots.  After third reboot it shows a recovery console with options for

*Continue

*Troubleshoot

*Turn off your PC

I choose troublehsoot and open a command prompt and when I tried to run

```
SFC /scannow
```

But receive the error: Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.

I tried to run
    chkdsk /r

And receive the error: Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.

I can boot into DSRM but I'm not sure how to proceed.  I try to demote the DC, but receive this error when supplying credentials:

```
Error verifying credentials: verification of user credential permissions failed. Failed to examine         the Active Directory forest. The error was: The operation cannot continue because LDAP connect/bind operation failed: error 58. Ther specificied server cannot perform the requested operation.)
```

Comment: Did you do anything silly, like configure the VM with nonexistent disks?

Comment: Did it used to start normally in this setup and just broke, or is this a migration scenario?

Comment: It used to start normally and then it just broke.  It was a secondary DC and one day i logged into the main DC and noticed a red flag about the second DC and that has lead me to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that this is not your *only* domain controller.

Delete the DC's computer object from Active Directory Users and Computers using a version of RSAT for Vista/2008 or later. Then, go into the AD Sites & Services snap-in and delete any reference to it in there. Then, reinstall the OS and promote the server again.

If directory services won't start, you can't do a clean demotion, so this is the best way to clean up a DC that's being taken out of service without a proper demotion. This is also why you can't demote in DSRM.

---

If this is your only DC, then do what Ryan says and pray for a miracle.

Comment: This is not my only DC. I also did NOT have a backup of it.  Deleted it from ADUC and ADSaS. Rebuilding now. Will include a backup going forward.

Answer (score 2):

The error code is "Directory Services cannot start."

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258062) has all the ntdsutil tricks you need to check your AD database.

Disregard that the article talks about Small Business Server - the principles are the same.

But here's the thing.  You really should read the whole article, because therein are a lot of useful bits of information, such as:

> Note Microsoft does not support domain controllers after Ntdsutil or
>   Esentutl is used to recover from Active Directory database corruption.
>   If you perform this kind of repair, you must rebuild the domain
>   controller for Active Directory to be in a supported configuration.
>   The repair command in Ntdsutil uses the Esentutl utility to perform a
>   lossy repair of the database. This kind of repair fixes corruption by
>   deleting data from the database. Only use this kind of repair as a
>   last resort.

So what you should be focusing on is restoring the domain controller from a system state backup.  You have a backup, right?  Well, if you don't, then you should just blow away the VM and build a new domain.  I'll assume you didn't have anything important on that domain controller anyway if you didn't have a backup.  :)

Answer (score 1):

My situation involved a physical server which was also an only server, so demotion/promotion would have been painful since all AD accounts would be lost in the process.

Fortunately, I found a better/simpler solution that usually works, or at least did for me.

- Boot into Directory Services Repair Mode (Troubleshoot / Startup Settings / Restart / Directory Services Repair Mode). It may do some repairs and reboot, requiring you to do this a second time.
- Login with a local admin account, since AD is not available.
- Delete (or rename) `C:\Windows\NTDS\*.log`.

And reboot normally.

However, you may also want to defrag the database while in DSRM:

- Open a Command Prompt (Win-R, CMD, Enter). Type `NTDSUTIL` and press Enter.
- Type `activate instance ntds` and press Enter.
- Type `Files` and press Enter.
- Type `Info` and press Enter. Verify the folder is actually `C:\Windows\NTDS`.
- Type `Compact to <path>` and press Enter. I created `C:\Windows\NTDS\Temp` and used that.
- Copy the new file Ntds.dit in the temp folder over top of the old one in NTDS, and delete all the *.log files.

Reboot normally.

References:

- http://www.symantec.com/business/support//index?page=content&pmv=print&impressions=&viewlocale=&id=TECH205836
- http://support.microsoft.com/?id=258062
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232122